# Post form data in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have just created a new project in larvel and I am trying to submit form in db but it is not saving data in db.
here is my form

```
   <form id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('updateadminprofile')}}"enctype="multipart/form-data" >


@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="font-size: 18px;">
        <strong>Success: </strong>

        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="userName"> Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name}"  value="name" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="userName"> Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description}"  value="description" />
    </div>
</div>
<button  style="margin-left: 30%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="sumbmit" >Save</button>
```

My route is

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'PrivatePages'], function () {
        Route::any('/updateadminprofile', ['as' => 'updateadminprofile', 
        'uses' => 'ProductController@UpdateAdminProfile']);
```

});

here is my contoller function

```
      public function UpdateAdminProfile(CreateProductRequest $request)
{
     $saveproduct = new Product();

    $saveproduct->name = $request->name;
    $saveproduct->description = $request->description;

    $saveproduct->save();
}
```

it is not saving record in db. and when i try to submit form it gives me below text,

```
 The page has expired due to inactivity. 

 Please refresh and try again.
```

when i added csrf in form it even not going to route specified in the action of form

Comment: try this, change action="{{ route('updateadminprofile')}}" in your form to action='ProductController@UpdateAdminProfile' lets see if it works.

Comment: the csrf field should be sent back to the server. how did you add it? use {{ csrf_field() }} within your form tag.

Comment: <form id="" method="post"  action="{{ route('updateadminprofile')}}" {{ csrf_field() }} >

Comment: <form id="" method="post"  action="{{ route('updateadminprofile')}}"  >

Comment: {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: i added like above methods but it is not working

Comment: did you try this? action='ProductController@UpdateAdminProfile' as commented above @raja

Comment: yes i also tried this but not working

Comment: `CreateProductRequest $request` should be `Request $request`

Comment: @Option except for the fact that he maybe has a CreateProductRequest which extends Request? (But we dont know if he has though)

Comment: @Clemenz, I will always state the obvious unless the op states it's been extended etc. Chances are the OP hasn't extended it.. Also, the OP is running a save function therefore indicating that there's data to be overwritten currently.. Again not stated so is it an insert query or an update?

Comment: @Option Ofcourse, but shouldnt you expect an internal server error then when calling the controller?

Comment: yes i have CreateproductRequest which is extended from Request

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are probably missing the CSRF field in your form. Also keep the Flash message out of your form.

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="font-size: 18px;">
    <strong>Success: </strong>

    {{ Session::get('success') }}
</div>
@endif

<form id="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="/updateadminprofile">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="name"> Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name"  value="name" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="description"> Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description}"  value="description" />
    </div>
</div>
<button style="margin-left: 30%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Edit: cleaned up some minor HTML errors and specified the route directly instead of a blade function. Could you try this?

Comment: i added csrf protection but it is now not even going to route specified in form action method

Comment: it just refreshes the same form after adding csrf field

Comment: Can you try my answer again? I edited some things and hardcoded the URL to post to.

Comment: no its not working. it just refreshes the page. Not going to route specified in action of form

Comment: i think this is the issue

Comment: i change this line to this

Comment: class CreateProductRequest extends FormRequest to class CreateProductRequest extends Request

Comment: but now it is giving me error "Class 'App\Http\Requests\Request' not found"

Comment: Did you import it right? You will need to use this line then: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by just adding following namespaces in the CreateProductRequest and ProductController
In Create CreateProductRequest updated following lines.

```
    use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
    class CreateProductRequest extends Request{}
```

In Product Controller i use following namespace
.

```
 use App\Http\Requests\CreateProductRequest;
```

Thanks All for your time and help